# Javascript validate a field that allows for multiple file upload. Check if a selection has been made?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a form that allows for multiple file uploads.

```
<input name="uploadedfile[]" type="file" multiple="true"/>
```

Now, I want to validate it using javascript to check if a file was selected. I tried the following but failed

```
if(form.uploadedfile.length < 1)
{
    alert("You Forgot to select an image");
    return false;
}
```

and I know its an array but i also tried

```
if(form.uploadedfile.value == '')
{
    alert("You Forgot to select an image");
    return false;
}
```

can someone help me out on this one.
Thanks

Comment: what are these brackets in your name attribute???

Comment: I don't think multiple="true" should be there, but there should be more than one uploadedFile[] in the form.

Comment: @Luke, the brackets are for multiple uploads, it is valid. Should work just fine in PHP, should give an array of uploadedFile. Just not sure how to access an array of input in JavaScript.

Comment: @jValdron - multiple="true" allows you to select multiple files at a time. The method u are suggesting is not user friendly as they will have to fill out each and every input individually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this example](http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload) they use a files property of the input, and check the length of that, something like this.

```
<input name="uploadedfile[]" id="uploadfile" type="file" multiple="true"/>
```

And the JS:

```
if(document.getElementById("uploadfile").files.length < 1)
{
   alert("You Forgot to select an image");
   return false;
}
```

Haven't been able to find any info about the files-property yet.

Comment: Hey, I had tried this before and it didnt work.
But when I looked at ur answer and reviewed mine, I realised that I had named the id as "uploadfile" and was checking for "uploadedfile" all the time. Hence I cudnt get it to work.
Silly Me! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

One approach is:

```
$('input[type="file"][multiple]').change(
    function(e){
        var numFiles = e.currentTarget.files.length;
        if (numFiles == 0){
            // no files
        }
        else {
            // files chosen
            console.log(numFiles);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Ytf3M/).